# Cannot load files from angular app deployed on Apache server

Tags: angular, apache, angular8, mime-types, angular9

I want to create an Angular app which is run on Apache server. Locally from `npm start` it's running well but from remote Apache deployment many files are missing. I tried to configure fonts and i18n files under the folder `src/assets/....` into `angular.json`:

```
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
```

But when I run the web page I get errors like:

```
633328.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
materialdesignicons-webfont14e6.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
fontawesome-webfont3295.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
fontawesome-webfont3295.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
materialdesignicons-webfont14e6.woff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
fontawesome-webfont3295.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
materialdesignicons-webfont14e6.ttf:
```

1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

So after research looks like I have to add mapping using this: https://www.thewebflash.com/set-the-correct-mime-types-for-woff-fonts-in-your-web-server/ but it's not working. I also tried to add this configuration: https://gist.github.com/vmilev/cf8ef05c2d77fc8aedd6c5831d724a77

But again no luck. Can you give me some idea how this can be fixed?

***.htaccess file***

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /angular/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>

AddType font/woff .woff
AddType font/woff2 .woff2
```

Comment: Could it be that you redirect all URLs to `index.html` regardless of whether the file exists or not? You should have a `RewriteCond` that checks for `-f` (files) or `-d` (directories). Could you post your relevant Apache config?

Comment: I use the default apache config with added .htaccess file. See the updated port.

Comment: Your .htaccess doesn't look very correct. You should correctly go to files or directories atleast, but then you rewrite to index.html, AND add a whole new rewrite block? In that block you always RewriteBase and always rewrite to index.html, you stop there because of `[L]` and then there's more unreachable rewrites. Maybe the 2nd `RewriteEngine On` removes previous rules and that causes the strange behavior?

Answer (score 1):

just add slash in styles.css before urls. Change from this

```
angular/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
```

to this

```
/angular/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
```

Comment: Thanks. So far so good but now I get `Failed to decode downloaded font: http://123.123.134.123/angular/angular/assets/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont14e6.woff2?v=1.4.57