# How to implement file path for different environments

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-i18n

I'm trying to implement ngx-translate from this [tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core):

Locally when I run the angular app using npm start it's working fine. But when I want to use custom subdir like this: `ng build  --output-path angular --base-href=/angular/` and to deploy it on Apache server the file is not found.

File is located under `src\assets\i18n\en.json`

I get multiple errors like this:

```
message: "Http failure response for http://123.123.123.123/assets/i18n/en.json: 404 Not Found"
```

With some luck I managed to solve this using this code:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, '/angular/assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

But now when I run locally using `ng start` the files is not found.

Do you know how this can be fixed in both cases?

Comment: what version of angular do you use?

Comment: I use Angular: 9.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must change in relative path

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

Comment: I have one additional question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61070841/cannot-load-files-from-angular-app-deployed-on-apache-server Have you faced this before?